# Creating an edit form from model containing Foreignkey?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am creating an app, where I am storing employee's complete information, now the problem with my development is that I am entering dependents of the employee in a manner that the Person which he adds as a dependent gets a entry in the Person model.

Dependent and DependentRelationship Model Look Like:

```
class Dependent(Person):
    """Dependent models: dependents of employee"""

     occupation = models.CharField(_('occupation'), max_length=50, null=True,
        blank=True)
     self_dependent = models.BooleanField(_('self dependent'))

 class DependentRelation(models.Model):
     """Dependent Relation Model for Employee"""

     employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee, verbose_name=_('employee'))
     dependent = models.ForeignKey(Dependent, verbose_name=_('dependent'))

     relationship = models.CharField(_('relationship with employee'),
         max_length=50)

     class Meta:
         ordering = ('employee', 'dependent',)
         unique_together = ('employee', 'dependent' )
```

I am using a ModelForm to enter the data for the dependent this is the form for adding dependent:

```
class DependentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    relationship = forms.CharField(_('relationship')) # TODO: max_length??
    class Meta:
       model = Dependent
```

I wanted to show all the Dependent's Information as well as the relationship with the employee, in the edit form. So is there a possible view.

Any suggestions or links can help me a lot.......

Thanks in Advance.....................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@login_required
def edit_dependents(request, id):
employee = request.user.get_profile() 
try:
    dependent = employee.dependent.get(id=id)
except Dependent.DoesNotExist:
    messages.error(request, "You can't edit this dependent(id: %s)." %id)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('core_show_dependent_details'))
dependent_relation = DependentRelation.objects.get(dependent=dependent, employee=employee)
if request.method == "POST":
    form = DependentForm(data=request.POST, instance=dependent)
    if form.is_valid():
        dependent = form.save(commit=False)
        dependent_relation = DependentRelation.objects.get(dependent=dependent, employee=employee)
        dependent_relation.relationship = form.cleaned_data['relationship']
        try:
            dependent_relation.full_clean()
        except ValidationError, e:
             form = DependentForm(data=request.POST)
        dependent.save()
        dependent_relation.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('core_show_dependent_details'))
else:
    form = DependentForm(instance=dependent,
        initial={'relationship': dependent_relation.relationship})
dictionary = {'form':form,'title':'Edit Dependents',}
return render_to_response('core/create_edit_form.html',dictionary, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

As I have defined my model form in my question, I created an edit form from the same with passing two arguments one is the instance of the dependent person with the query as

```
dependent = employee.dependent.get(id = id)
```

where the second id is the dependent's id.

Secondly I saved the relationship in the DependentRelationship model with all its attributes, having the value of relationship, and dependent from the ModelForm.

So in this way I was able to create the edit form for my app. After a long search which is working good.